# Shift-left a 'double' operand

Tags: c++, c, double, bit-shift

The following function shifts-left a `double` operand:

```
double shl(double x,unsigned long long n)
{
    unsigned long long* p = (unsigned long long*)&x;
    *p += n << 52;
    return x;
}
```

Is this function guaranteed to work correctly on all platforms?

You may assume a valid combination of `x` and `n` (i.e., `x*2^n` does not overflow).

---

In other words, I am asking whether or not the language standard dictates the following:

1. Exponent bits of type `double` are 52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62
2. Bit-size of `double` equals bit-size of `unsigned long long` equals 64
3. Strict-aliasing rule for `double` and `unsigned long long` is not broken

If the answers for C and for C++ are different, then I would like to know each one of them.

Comment: I don't think the standard promises any of the 3 items you list.

Comment: Crossworks C for example can have 32b doubles

Comment: @Leeor: A 32-bit `double` type does not meet the requirements of the C standard. It sounds like Crossworks C is a non-conforming implementation.

Comment: The strict aliasing rules are different in C than in C++

Comment: @KeithThompson, interesting, they claim to be, but you raise a valid point about the min size below.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: True, and also different between revisions of those standards, but this is forbidden by all of them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, neither C nor C++ dictates the representation of floating-point types in the language standard, although the IEEE format is recommended and a macro (`__STDC_IEC_559__`) is supposed to be available to detect whether it is in use.

Your solution has multiple problems in addition to different representations.  You already spotted the strict aliasing violation... the optimizer might turn your whole function into a no-op, since no `double` is modified between the beginning of the function and the return value, it can assume `x` isn't changed.  You could additionally have an overflow problem -- you would need some form of saturating arithmetic that doesn't allow the result to carry into the sign bit.

However, you don't need to mess with any of that, since the standard library already contains the function you're trying to write.

It is named `ldexp` (and `ldexpf` for `float`).

Comment: Well, I did say "assume that `x*2^n` does not overflow"... But apart from that it answers my question to full (double) precision. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

For C++:

1. No. C++ does not require IEEE floating point. It doesn't even require binary exponents.
2. Absolutely not. Unsigned long long may be more than 64 bits. Double need not be 64 bits.
3. That sort of type punning is unsafe.

Comment: `double` can't be less than 64 bits, due to the requirements on values in `float.h`

Comment: @BenVoigt: If I recall correctly, `double` must be more than 32 bits, but I don't think it needs to be 64 bits. I don't remember the exact details.

Comment: Also, `x` might not be correctly aligned for `unsigned long long`.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Ah, right.  The minimum of 10 decimal digits precludes 32-bit double, but the minimum (decimal) exponent range is +/- 37, the same as for `float`, so it doesn't have to be as many total bits as IEEE754 double precision.

Answer (score 1):

This code definitely doesn't shift a double operand to the left. It does some kind of bit manipulation, probably in the hope that the exponent of a double number would be changed.

As it is, the code invokes undefined behaviour, because an lvalue is written using the type long long and then read using the type double. As a result, anything could happen. That's the most unportable code you could get.

Comment: Thanks, I meant the equivalent for left-shifting.

Comment: Your paraphrasing of strict-aliasing isn't quite right. In dynamically-allocated memory, the effective type of the object is whatever was last stored in it; but for a named variable the effective type is the declared type; e.g. you can't declare an `unsigned long long` and then write a float to it and read the float back again (even if alignment is correct).  (This is for C; C++ is slightly different)